# Google Maps (flash) - Selecting countries

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps, geolocation

I want to be able to overlay a country with a color. I found this on thread on Google groups, but does it work in Europe/Scandinavia/Asia?

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/ce7dad51143378f4

The example only shows in the USA. Well frankly, i want to be able to do the same thing as the example does, but for my cause... kinda.

And yes, I'm new to this so have that in mind. I have looked in recent and relevant posts, but that doesn't help me at the moment.

I'm grateful for all the hints and tips, help and what else you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***

Wasn't even paying attention that this was a flash question. Below is a link to a video tutorial on getting started with the maps API in flash + adding custom overlay objects. The video also has the project files downloadable in the top right of the screen.

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=104

***Original Answer***

I did a quick google search and found this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Custom_Overlays

I've never really messed with the google maps API's before, just a little bit in flash. Anyway from having a quick read over this looks like what you'd be after. You can define custom overlay objects and you can also tie them to long/lat so you're not restricted to any location.

Basic tutorial of adding a builtin overlay with jQuery:

http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics

And a random link I found that has a boatload of maps api's tutorials:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

Comment: Glad I can help out. That website (gotoandlearn) is a fantastic free resource for learning flash.